# Trying to get injected service for seeding data in ASP.NET core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ef-core-2.2

In ConfigureServices I say

```
   services.AddDbContext<PwdrsDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PwdrsDbConnection"));
            });

     RegisterServices(services);
```

In configure I say

```
 SeedData.SeedDatabase(app);
```

In the static seed method I say

```
public class SeedData
{
    public static void SeedDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        PwdrsDbContext context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<PwdrsDbContext>();
    }
}
```

and when I run it says

Cannot resolve scoped service 'Pwdrs.Infra.Data.Context.PwdrsDbContext' from root provider

I need the dbcontext to seed the data but what am I missing?

Comment: Just create the dbcontext instance yourself. You don't need the DI container to manage this instance since you will only seed "once" under specific conditions.

Comment: Seeding data doesn't belong in Configure, it's for configuring the HTTP request pipeline. EF has a seeding mechanism itself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the services from your ConfigureServices method into the `Configure` method separately:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app, 
    IServiceProvider services) // <- magic here
{
   // ...
   SeedData.SeedDatabase(services);
}

public class SeedData
{
    public static void SeedDatabase(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        PwdrsDbContext context = services.GetRequiredService<PwdrsDbContext>();
    }
}
```